# How to transfer object to converter parameter in dynamic binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

```
var b=new Binding();
b.Source=myobj;
b.Path=new PropertyPath("Text",myParameter);//<-- myParemter is int value
b.Converter=new FollConverter();
control.SetBinding(UserControl.VisibilityProperty,b);
```

in my converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
if(parameter!=null)  //<-- PROBLEM IS HERE, ALWAYS NULL
}
```

How to transfer object in dynamic binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ain't how you use converter paramters, this [`PropertyPath` contstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587924.aspx) has nothing to do with that `paramter` in `Convert`.

```
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
b.ConverterParameter = myParamter;
```